How to export Org to LaTeX over TRAMP?
I am working remotely over TRAMP. I have an Org file on a remote machine and I would like to export it to LaTeX and PDF, but I can't install pdflatex or the LaTeX dependencies on that machine (I have all the dependencies on my local machine but Org fails when trying to call the remote's nonexistent pdflatex).
My question is: How can I export a remote Org file to LaTeX and PDF using the local shell environment (and ideally wind up with the output .tex and .pdf files on the remote machine)?
Some possible directions:

SSH-level: Add a host to my SSH config with the same address as the remote but set up to somehow use the local environment. With port forwarding?
Remote-level: Configure the remote shell itself to pass relevant commands back to the local machine. With port forwarding?
Emacs-level: Make a command that copies the Org file (and any included files like images) to the local machine, does the export, and then copies back the .tex and .pdf files. In that case, is there a robust way to include all included files, or would it be best to just make sure that they're all in the same remote directory and then just copy over the whole thing? Related: answer to "Run local command on remote file with TRAMP?"
TRAMP-level: Configure TRAMP to execute relevant commands locally. I also need the remote shell's environment to have my remote Conda profile configured for use.

